# Not able to reference new column?

Tags: sql, oracle, bi-publisher

I am unable to add in a condition for the new 'Role1' column created:

```
SELECT NVL(SUBSTR(ACCESS_PATH_INFO, 0, INSTR(ACCESS_PATH_INFO, '>')-1), ACCESS_PATH_INFO) AS Role1
from INCIDENTS
where Role1 = 'DB'
```

I needed to create this column to remove all data after the first '>' :

```
DB1238 > DB102839 > DB10293892804
HJ3948203 > HJ10293 > HJ11

Role1
=====  
DB1238 
HJ3948203
```

The error I am getting when trying to reference the new column 'Role1' in the query is:

> ORA-00904: "ROLE1": invalid identifier

What do I have to change to be able to use the new column in the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try please

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT NVL(SUBSTR(ACCESS_PATH_INFO, 0, 
                        INSTR(ACCESS_PATH_INFO, '>') - 1
                       ), ACCESS_PATH_INFO
                ) AS Role1
      FROM INCIDENTS
     ) t1
WHERE t1.Role1 = 'DB'
```

Comment: Sorry, this is my fail. Add '*' after SELECT. I have corrected answer right now.

Comment: Oh duh I should've noticed that! It worked, thank you :)